# How to alert a user of a very important task on a mobile app?

Tags: notification, alerts

We have a task application wherein a service provider must be able to see an incoming job right away as it is time sensitive.

We'd like an alert that's similar to a call (it has that urgency to it) without the alert being an actual "call". We feel that a push notification or even an SMS alert is too subtle.

I'm not sure what's the best way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps you could create some sort of system that checks every minute if that task has already been flagged as 'noticed'. If it hasn't, send it again.

Comment: Normal alerts are designed to be fairly unintrusive to the user by displaying visual information when the user looks at the device. If you want more urgency, the standard procedure is to add a continuous sound (an alarm) with the notification to force the user to interact with the device.

Answer (score 2):

Since the alert is very important, must not be missed and acted upon right away (please double check with users and stakeholders that this true), one option is to create an alert similar to a call :

When the event happens produce a loud sound and a flashing message. The sound will continue for 30 seconds unless the user stops it. If the 30 seconds elapse without any action from the user then display the missed alert on the desktop of the mobile (just like missed calls).

Answer (score 0):

It should be an alert. Alerts creates 'an action should be taken' state for the user so it clearly says that it's urgent rather than call or push notification. User can postpone alert (snooze etc.), acknowledge or discard.